# Como posso mover um elemento de um ArrayList para o último elemento ?

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, collection

Gostaria de saber se existe algum método para efectuar a operação, sem ser concatenar manualmente. 
Exemplo do que pretendia:

[1,2,3,4] -> [1,3,4,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim, é fazer troca dos elementos.

```
public static <E> void swap(List<E> list, int idx1, int idx2){
    E aux = list.get(idx1);
    list.set(idx1, list.get(idx2));
    list.set(idx2, aux);
}
```

Para trocar  o 2 com o 4 voce escreveria

```
swap(list, 1, list.size() - 1);
```